# Why is "$\phi \to \psi$" equivalent to "$\neg\phi \vee \psi$"?

Tags: logic

I'm studying rules of inference with [this YouTube video by TheTrevTutor](https://youtu.be/ePsgmqE7pJs?t=361). In one proof, I can't understand how $\phi \to \psi$ gets replaced by $\neg\phi \vee \psi$ (Step 6 to Step 7).

[image]

What name of this rule? The video calls it "the definition of $\vee$ with respect to the arrow".

If someone would suggest name of this rule I could google it and know more about it.

Thank you.

Comment: Look up the definition of "implies"

Comment: See the [followin post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2642912/understanding-of-material-implication)

Comment: [Material Implication rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference))

Comment: A word from the inventor himself: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3406816/mathematical-logic-unusual-question/3406881#3406881

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name you are looking for is "[material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference))".

Answer (score 0):

The formulae $\phi\rightarrow\psi$ (implication) and $\neg\phi\vee\psi$ (not $\phi$ or $\psi$)have the same semantics, i.e., if you assign truth values to $\phi$ and $\psi$, both formulae have the same truth values.

Comment: @DonThousand : No.  Contrast material implication with [strict implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_conditional).

Answer (score 0):

The implication ($\phi \to \psi$)  means that one of the following scenarios is occuring: both $\phi$ and $\varphi$ are false, both are true, or $\varphi$ is true and $\phi$ is false [this only excludes the scenario where $\phi$ is true and $\varphi$ is false].

The "or" statement ($\neg\phi \vee \psi$) is only false in the scenario where $\phi$ is true and $\varphi$ is false, which is exactly when the implication is false.